# OpenVPN: Error: private key password verification failed

Tags: openvpn, ubuntu-14.04

I have setup the openvpn but when I run the command:- 
**"sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn"**, I am asked this question "Enter Private Key Password:". Which private key password is the openvpn actually asking for? Is it my username's or root password. I tried both but nothing works. Is it actually asking for password that may have been configured in the server(because I only have a client.ovpn file, received from the server). Can anyone please suggest regarding this kind of issue. The other questions are similar to mine but not the same & they didnt help me. Please suggest. Following are the errors:-

```
Enter Private Key Password:
WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the 
auth-nocache option to prevent this
Error: private key password verification failed
2017 Exiting due to fatal error
```

Comment: Private key password refers tot he password on your private key. This would have been set up when you created your key pair.